# printing multiple combined tables if date is equal

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using postgres 14.2
I have identical table for each currency, below example for eur and usd.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DOLLAR
(
    id                      serial PRIMARY KEY,
    updateTime              timestamp,
    //some more columns
);  

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EURO
(
    id                      serial PRIMARY KEY,
    updateTime              timestamp,
    //some more columns
);
```

Now I need 2 things:

1. select all records that have same value under `updateTime` and then print them both (paired).

In other words (pseudo code):

```
foreach e in EURO
  if (exist d in DOLLAR) and (d.updateTime == e.updateTime)
    print (e,d)
```

2. Print all rows from EURO that are not printed above

To make things easier `updateTime` is unique in particular table

Comment: "*I have identical table for each currency*" Could this be a single table with a currency column?

Answer (score 0):

> *I have identical table for each currency*

This should probably be single table with a currency column. If so, you'd do the same thing but as a [self-join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_self.asp).

> select all records that have same value under updateTime and then print them both (paired).

Inner join the tables on updateTime.

```
select updateTime, dollar.id, euro.id
from dollar
join euro on dollar.updateTime = euro.updateTime
```

Note that [`timestamp`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) is accurate to microseconds, so you might want to [truncate it](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC). If you do this, you'll need to change your unique index to include the truncation.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX dollar_updateTime_seconds_idx ON dollar(date_trunc('second', updateTime);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX euro_updateTime_seconds_idx ON euro(date_trunc('second', updateTime);
```

> Print all rows from EURO that are not printed above

Do a [left excluding join](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins). This is a left join on euro, so all euro columns are included, but then exclude those which have no matching dollar row.

```
select euro.*
from euro
left join euro on dollar.updateTime = euro.updateTime
where dollar.id is null
```